# UIWebView under the Navigation Bar only on portrait mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

My app is a simple Master-Detail applciation, based on a Split View Controller (for the iPhone 6+).
The Master View is listing the news of my Web Site, and the Detail View is showing the news, embedded in a UIWebView.

The problem is that the UIWebView is starting under the Navigation Bar, but only on portrait mode. On landscape mode, the UIWebView is correctly displayed. Here 2 screenshots :

[Portait mode](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/40/1412522064-image1.png)

[Landscape mode](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/40/1412522074-image2.png)

As you can see, the head of our dear French minister is cropped in portrait mode !

Any ideas on how to fix that ?

Comment: Can't you just a solid navigation bar instead of translucent?

Comment: No, I would like to keep the translucent nav bar. It works on landscape mode, so I'm pretty sure it's only need a little tweak to fix this.

Comment: Using a solid navbar would place the uiwebview below the navbar which is what you want, or place the uiwebview below the nav bar and handle the autolayouts appropriately

Comment: I want the Web View to start below the navigation bar and to be visible by transparency under it when I scroll down. It works fine on landscape mode, why not in portait ?